# Embed message loop doesnt stop

Tags: discord.js

If I type pingtest, my bot is sending the embed message over and over again (infinite loop)

```
if (message.content='pingtest') {
    message.channel.send({embed: {

            color: 000000,
            author: {
              name: client.user.username,
              icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
            },
            title: "A RAID HAS BEGUN (for the Dark Side)",
            description: "",
            fields: [{
                name: "------------------------------",
                value:"Write !raid to enter."
              }

            ],
            footer: {
              icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
            }
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: does the loop trigger if a message with "pingtest" is sent or does it trigger if any message is sent?

Comment: Can you add more of your code?

Comment: @Jamesm with any message

Comment: Could you try if (message.content ==='pingtest') for me and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** In your `if` statement, you're using the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), `=`.
**Solution:** Use an [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators) (i.e. `===`) to compare `message.content` instead.
**Explanation:** Right now, your code is *setting* `message.content` instead of *comparing* it. This means that no matter what `message.content` is, you're receiving the intended result of "pingtest." As for the looping, I'm going to guess that you're allowing messages from other bots in your message event. Therefore, when the bot sees its own message, it triggers the same faulty code again, creating a chain reaction.
**Revised Code:**

```js
if (message.author.bot) return; // bots will no longer trigger a command

if (message.content === 'pingtest') { // comparing message.content with ===
  // < your code for the 'pingtest' command >
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make embed for

```
if(message.content.startsWith('pingtest'))
   let embed = new Discord.Embed
       .setColor('color')
       .setTitle('title')
       .setAuthor(`${client.user.username}`)
       .setDescreption('Descreption')
       .addField('Field)
      message.channel.send(embed)
```